# Adding DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 resulting in syntax error

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to enable docker buildkit using **`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`** to my build command in a **github actions workflow**.

But it complains about this syntax:

```
   build_and_push_docker_image_from_artifact:
    needs: build
    name: Build/Push Image => GitHub Container Registry
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: dist-artifact
          path: app
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - run: DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret service-account-json-key -t ghcr.io/xxxxx/xxxxx-database:latest -f docker/database.Dockerfile .
```

As you can see I also tried using `setup-buildx-action@v2`

**Error I get is:**

```
Invalid workflow file
You have an error in your yaml syntax
```

**Note:** `xxxxx` - is just me hiding sensitive info for this post

Comment: I think you can use `env` section to specify the environment variable.

Comment: Also how is your `steps`  are defined?

Comment: I'll update it with my steps to show you

Comment: example? (I think you can use env section). I don't know how I'd reference that still to make sure my command doesn't bomb out

Comment: See [this section](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsenv). `DOCKER_BUILDKIT ` appears to be a environment variable here.

Comment: The error doesn't contain the line and column number? The above workflow looks fine. Are you sure that this error is not coming from someplace else in your workflow? Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to lint your workflow. Looks like https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action is already using a BuildKit container so you don't have to do anything special with it.